# D3v4 inserting new nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

EDIT: [added codepen example](http://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/vabBNz)

I'm experimenting with D3v4 force simulation, but I am currently unable to properly add new nodes to a graph. Here's the setup

```
var svgRef = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",svgWidth)
    .attr("height",svgHeight)
    .on("mousedown",svgClick);

var nodes_data = [{id: "0"},{id: "1"},{id: "2"}];
var links_data = [{source:"1",target:"2"}];

var linksRef = svgRef
    .selectAll(".link")         
    .data(links_data).enter()
    .append("line").attr("class", "link");

var nodesRef = svgRef
    .append("g").attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes_data).enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag()...);

nodesRef.append("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius);
```

I'm creating a group for individual nodes to hold their `circle` and `title` and `text` etc. and all these nodes are created under a greater "nodes" group. The end result looks like this:

```
<svg>
    ...
    <g class="nodes">
        <g class="node">
            <circle>
            <text>
            ...
        </g>
        <g class="node"></g>
        <g class="node"></g>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

Then I'm adding a new node to my data and *trying* to insert it in the graph

```
function svgClick(){

    // add new node
    nodes_data.push({id: nodeCount++, "x":d3.event.X, "y":d3.event.y});

    // restart simulation
    simulation.nodes(nodes_data).on("tick", ticked);

    // insert new nodes
    nodeEnter = svgRef
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes_data).enter()
        .append("g").attr("class", "node")
        .call(d3.drag()...)
        .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", nodeRadius);

    // merge new nodes
    nodesRef = nodeEnter.merge(nodesRef);
}
```

2 things that are going wrong that I'm unable to fix:

- <strike>the inserted node does not appear at the mouse coordinates</strike>
  *Figured this one out, just a typo in `d3.event.X` where **X** had to be lowercas*
- the inserted node is not added in the `<g class="nodes">` but below. I can't find a way to select it properly

Like so:

```
<svg>
    <g class="nodes">
        <g class="node"></g>
        <g class="node"></g>
    </g>
    <g class="node"></g>  // <--- inserted here
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried to give you an answer but there are some missing data. Could you create a Codepen to help people to help you? You could start from here https://codepen.io/macio/pen/GrQWrK.

Comment: There you go!
https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/vabBNz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second issue: "the inserted node is not added in the  but below. I can't find a way to select it properly", how you enter the new nodes explains why you end up with the structure you have:

```
nodeEnter = svgRef
 .selectAll(".node")   // select all elements with class node in the svg
 .data(nodes_data)     // bind new data to them
  .enter()             // enter new nodes where needed
 .append("g")          // append a g for each new node needed to the svg
```

This appends new nodes straight to the parent svg: `svgRef.selectAll(...)...`.

If we want to append new nodes to a parent, we must first select that parent. If we wanted to use the `g` with class `nodes` as the parent element for new nodes, we would use: `svgRef.select(".nodes").selectAll(...)...`.

This would look like:

```
nodeEnter = svgRef
  .select(".nodes")     // select the parent g with class nodes
  .seleactAll(".node")  // select all nodes in that parent
  .data(nodes_data)     // bind new data to them
  .enter()              // enter new nodes where needed
  .append("g")          // append a g for each new node needed to the g with class nodes
```

*Also, you want nodeEnter to be the `g` elements, not the `circle` elements, so you could split your chaining here. The circles also don't need the class node as the parent g has it*

For the positioning, you are using `d3.event.X` rather than `d3.event.x` and in the codepen, as opposed to the question, you are using cx,cy properties for the node (the force takes the position to be the x,y properties).

Here's an [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBvNpL).

*Keep in mind that the if the tick winds down new nodes aren't positioned as they are placed on each tick, not on append (reset alpha if you want to ensure a tick). Also the jumpiness you might see is due to d3.forceCenter which seeks to ensure the center of gravity of the nodes is the specified point (you can apply a positioning force instead of d3.forceCenter if you want to avoid that issue)*

Comment: I updated the [pen](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/EpraqW?editors=0010) with the `select(".nodes")` but I'm getting a weird result with the nodes are not redrawn. Do I need to .restart() somewhere?

Comment: @VincentDM, my apologies, I didn't add the selectAll statement needed: `.select(".nodes").selectAll(".nodes")` in the answer's second code block - I copied the first code block and only did half the modification, the pen in the answer should be correct still though. I've updated the answer to correct the mistake.

Comment: ok awesome! so here's the [final working pen](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/EpraqW?editors=0011)  thanks ^^